# Elasticsearch composite aggregation throws "[x_content_parse_exception] [1:131] [composite] failed to parse field [sources]"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**Context:**
Running tests on local Elasticsearch 8.6.1 deployment, using elastic Java client (same version).
Index mapping is pretty simple - two keyword fields ("strKey1" and "strKey1") in each document.

**The problem:**
All my composite aggregation search queries are throwing exception:

```
[es/search] failed: [x_content_parse_exception] [1:131] [composite] failed to parse field [sources]
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [x_content_parse_exception] [1:131] [composite] failed to parse field [sources]
    at app//co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:282)
    at app//co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:148)
    at app//co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1833)
```

queries implemented as:

```java
var rqst = SearchRequest.of(b -> b
        .index(coords.getIndexName())
        .size(1000)
        .query(query)
        .aggregations("aggre", a -> a
                .composite(ca -> ca
                        .size(100)
                        .sources(Map.of("strKey1", strKey1, "strKey2", strKey2))
                )
        )
);
client.search(rqst, Void.class);
```

I looked into actual http request in which this query transformed and it seems ok:

```
SearchRequest: POST /the_index/_search?typed_keys=true {"aggregations":{"aggre":{"composite":{"size":100,"sources":[{"strKey2":{"terms":{"field":"strKey2"}},"strKey1":{"terms":{"field":"strKey1"}}}]}}},"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":1000}
```

Tried to execute this request manually with curl and ***it works***! Returning expected aggregation results!

I also tried other aggregation types (multiTerms for instance) via Java client and they are working as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any problems specific to composite aggregations in Java client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the mistake was pretty dumb.

You should set each source in separate Map objects:

```java
.composite(ca -> ca
        .size(100)
        .sources(Map.of("strKey1", strKey1), Map.of("strKey2", strKey2))
)
```

instead of:

```java
.composite(ca -> ca
        .size(100)
        .sources(Map.of("strKey1", strKey1, "strKey2", strKey2))
)
```